# how to add Urdu language support to Tesseract OCR in react native

Tags: react-native, ocr

I am using the [react-native-tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/jonathanpalma/react-native-tesseract-ocr) package and I am trying to convert image to text but in the **Urdu** language, when I tried to change `LANG_ENGLISH` to `LANG_URDU`, it shows nothing, I need some suggestions on how to change it to Urdu.

```js
import TesseractOcr, {
    LANG_ENGLISH,
    useEventListener,
} from 'react-native-tesseract-ocr';
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no support for Urdu language in react native tesseract package.